# Use factory to resolve dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, rebus

We have a websolution with autofac. Now we want to reuse things in a windows service/console app where things are only available when a message comes in from an enterprise bus.

**I have the following service to reuse**

```
public SettingsService : ISettingsService {
    public readonly ITenantIdentifer _tenantIdentifier
    public SettingsService (ITenantIdentifier tenantIdentifier) {
       this._tenantIdentifier =tenantIdentifier; 
    }
    // do other stuff
}
```

**The current working setup**

the `ITenantIdentifier` for the webcontext is simply registered for the webapplication using `builder.RegisterType<WebTenantIdentifier>().As<ITenantIdentifier>();`.
Evething works fine.

**Our enterprise bus**

The enterprise bus can not resolve the `ITenantIdentifier` until the message is available.  So we created a `MessageTenantIdentifier` and registered a factory.

```
 public class MessageTenantIdentifier : ITenantIdentifier
 {
    public delegate MessageTenantIdentifier Factory(int tenantId);
public MessageTenantIdentifier(int tenantId, IOtherDependency stuff)
    {
        _tenantId = tenantId;
        // ...
    }
}

// somewhere else the this is registered     
builder.RegisterType<MessageTenantIdentifier >().As<ITenantIdentifier>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterGeneratedFactory<MessageTenantIdentifier.Factory>();
```

**The problem**
The factory can only be used when the message is being handled in a

```
public class MsgTypeHandler : IHandleMessages<MsgType>
{
    public MsgTypeHandler(ISettingsService settingsService, MessageTenantIdentifier factory) { ...}
    public async Task Handle(MsgType message)
    {
        var tenantId = message.TenantId;
        // THIS IS THE MOMENT I CAN CONFIGURE THE MessageTenantIdentifier
        var tenantIdentifier = factory.Invoke(tenantId);

        // but this factory is not used against the ISettingsService.  The service to be reused.  <== THE REAL PROBLEM
    }
}
```

**The question**

So, how can I solve this issue? E.g. how should I setup the registration of the MessageTenantIdentifier in the servicebus?
Or is my dependency setup just plain wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `MsgTypeHandler` class needs an `ISettingsService`, but the entire object graph can't be resolved until the tenant ID is available, that means that the `MsgTypeHandler` is the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot). That's OK, but that means that this is where you resolve your entire object graph, so don't inject individual services here; instead, inject the factory you need:

```
public class MsgTypeHandler : IHandleMessages<MsgType>
{
    public MsgTypeHandler(ISettingsServiceFactory factory) {...}

    public async Task Handle(MsgType message)
    {
        var tenantId = message.TenantId;
        ISettingsService svc = this.factory.Create(tenantId);

        // User svc here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, So I have to write my own factory method because the composition root can't depend on the DI-framework in this case.  (Still wondering if autofac has no way of resolving this)...

Comment: @dampee You can [write the factory in various ways](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory), including letting your DI Container take care of the details.

Comment: I get it.  I really need to read a book on the topic.  Is your book still a good reference, or would you advice any other?

Comment: @dampee I'd still recommend mine; it's deliberately written to be as timeless as possible.